How to use perilla oil for wood finishing
A substantial amount of literature exists regarding the use of pure linseed oil (from seeds of Linum usitatissimum) and pure tung oil (from seeds of Vernicia fordii) for wood finishing. I would have loved to use linseed oil or tung oil (or its close sibling — oil from the seeds of the mu oil tree [Vernicia montana]), but they have all proven very difficult and/or expensive for me to obtain. What I do have is an abundance of Perilla frutescens plants from which I can press the seeds to extract perilla oil, which is a drying oil.
Now the problem is that I could not find step-by-step instructions for the use of pure perilla oil to protect wood. Does perilla oil have to be mixed with some kind of solvent before being applied to wood? If so, which solvent and in what proportions? How many coats of perilla oil is recommended? What are the drying and curing times? If you have experience or knowledge, please guide me in the use of perilla oil for wood protection.

You can pretty much finish — I should say 'finish' — wood with any oil. And I do mean any oil, since machinists seem to often use 3-In-One or something similar on wooden components on tools they've made, and residual WD40 is often not removed from wood. Neither does the wood any harm, but just like using a food-grade mineral oil it doesn't do it much good either! The bottom line is, if you want to protect wood you just don't use a straight oil, period. So the real questions here aren't so much can you or how to it's should you. What's this for? What level of protection are you hoping for?

If you're OK with the minimal protection and there being no real rules on how to apply the established drying oils just start with a known application method and see how you go. You'll very likely find that 1 coat is not enough, and at least 2 is required for a uniform look; 3 is often the sweet spot. Don't thin the oil with anything, that's just a way to slow down the finishing process at the end of the day. It does NOT improve penetration as is so often blindly repeated online, at least not to a degree noticeable with the naked eye — in general you need a high-power loop or a microscope!

You still looking for an Answer here Flux or did you find enough info with further searching?

@Graphus Still looking for an answer.

FYI for future reference, I found some info on this (actually the only hands-on info that came up, and it was right at the top of the page) literally 10 seconds after reading your Q..... so you might want to work on your Google-fu. However I'm glad you didn't find that as it's just one dude's use-case and my perspective on this is completely different which is why I'm not including the link in my Answer, but look on SawMillCreek for "Has anyone used Perilla oil?" to read it for yourself — FWIW I think the key takeaway is that he wasn't using it as a standalone finish.


Does perilla oil have to be mixed with some kind of solvent before being applied to wood? If so, which solvent and in what proportions?

There's no 'have to' when talking about diluting oils. This isn't just by how much or using which solvent (a hotly debated detail), it's also whether to.
If you've looked at much finishing advice for the two key finishing oils, BLO and tung, you will most definitely have seen a lot of advice to thin the oil for at least the first coat which is presumably what prompted the question. However it is worth noting that others don't.1
My experience using a number of oils (at least six, including non-traditional ones) has shown me that diluting does nothing but thin the oil. That's a "Duh." of course but the ramifications of this aren't completely obvious — it mean one thing and only one thing: you apply less oil. And that's it2.

How many coats of perilla oil is recommended?

Regardless of whether there are recommendations for this see above. Just like with everything else about finishing in oil different sources tell us different things. Even with the two main finishing oils varied sources agree on nearly no details, clearly telling us that there are no absolutes with this sort of thing.
Basically I think what it boils down to is, you apply coats until you're happy with how the piece looks.
It will nearly always be true that one coat is never enough to give wood a consistent, uniformly wetted appearance and won't yield a consistent surface finish. As a rule of thumb, two should basically be considered the bare minimum needed. Three coats will often be found to be the sweet spot, with really no upper limit — an oft-quoted traditional finishing regime for BLO eventually amounts to 21 coats of oil, applied over the course of the first year!


What are the drying and curing times?

This should really be a separate Question but I'll cover it here because it's simply impossible to answer. It's unanswerable for even known oils like pure tung oil, raw linseed oil or BLO because there are tons of variables.
Processing to produce a product like Polymerised Tung Oil or BLO can tend to unify the drying time from batch to batch, but with oils that are minimally processed (e.g. "raw" or "cold-pressed") you must expect to see natural variation since it's a natural product3.
On top of that in your case, details of the oil extraction are unknown and introduces another variable. How much of the "foots" are removed will alter the drying (and other) characteristics of the oil.
Now those factors aside, the drying conditions in your working space are another variable as is the amount applied, the wood(s) you'll be working with etc.
So, it'll take as long as it takes :-)
"Drying"
Do bear in mind that there's no actual drying time with an oil. This is merely a useful shorthand.
If the drying properties of your oil are slightly faster than those of raw linseed oil (as some sources state) you can expect it to take numerous days between the first two or three coats.
Curing
Total cure time? Anybody's guess. But think a month plus rather than weeks to give you at least an approximate timeframe.

Now my personal recommendation is that you don't use the oil as a standalone finish except if:

you have lots of time to finish the project;
and it is a decorative object that won't see much handling, or a practical item that needs little protection (such as a bookshelf);

For something that does need greater protection and/or a more uniform surface gloss, use the oil as many now use BLO, purely to 'pop' the grain (deepen colour and increase contrast). Then finish over the top of it with something else that will provide the actual protection. This has a number of advantages, the first being that it's substantially faster. Additionally, even finishing in shellac (which isn't very strong) you'll end up with a surface that's more resistant to scuffs, dust and general soiling.

1 Even among what are or purport to be finishing pros a fair proportion say to thin the first coat, and might go so far as to state outright that this is necessary. Just to reiterate, this is clearly demonstrated to be incorrect by the other people who don't do this and you can't tell the finished items apart.
2 The same sources mentioned in 1 may (often will) additionally tell you that it's to improve penetration. This is also false, at least to any degree that you can notice. By all means do side-by-side comparisons for yourself to confirm if you have any doubts.
3 Even from the same source expect some variation year to year. This is something well known in the linseed oil world.

What I've gotten from your answers over the years is, "don't bother finishing with oil, it's way too much work for the results you get". I appreciate that input and have kept it in my back pocket. ;)

@FreeMan, yes but not just that! After all that effort and time you end up with surface protection below that of a couple or three coats of "Danish oil" or "Teak Oil" or "Tung Oil Finish" (which are all some variation of the same basic thing, with minor tweaks to formula) apply the exact same way, and every one of them dries way faster.... Going further, same deal with wiping on diluted poly. This, no surprise, gives even more protection and is also applied the exact same way, but, with the advantage that you don't have to be so scrupulous about wiping away every trace of excess. [contd]

What's even better is that in a lot of cases there's usually no real difference in how the wood ends up looking straight-on. Obviously there are sheen differences for a given no. of coats, with pure varnish building the most sheen along with the greatest protection, but in terms of grain pop there can be zero difference in effect in a lot (probably the majority) of woods. On wood where there is a diff, and the user is super fussy cos it's subtle, it's simple — oil first, then switch to something else. This is how a lot of French polished stuff was done, so this is not a new trick by any means.
